# How to fix "TypeError: Object of type Row is not JSON serializable" obviously created by "render_template" with Flask Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am building a web app with Flask. It is the dashboard of my marketing software. In my marketing software, users can create some campaigns.

In a campaign, there are several tasks. When a user wants to edit a task, I get this "Internal Server Error" page.

When I check the log, I can see this error:

```
TypeError: Object of type Row is not JSON serializable
```

So I added some "print()" everywhere to identify the line which produce this issue.
I think I found it but there is absolutely nothing of json there!

These is part of the code:

```
print(f"2409 ==================================================================================")
print(f"""
platform_details.name : {platform_details.name} {type(platform_details.name)}
categories_platforms : {categories_platforms} {type(categories_platforms)}
platform_details : {platform_details} {type(platform_details)}
category : {category} {type(category)}
task : {task} {type(task)}
type_task : {type_task} {type(type_task)}
taskuser : {taskuser} {type(taskuser)}
campaign : {campaign} {type(campaign)}
list_place_holders : {list_place_holders} {type(list_place_holders)}
form : {form} {type(form)}
AB_testing_result : {AB_testing_result} {type(AB_testing_result)}
""")
return render_template('task.html', title=platform_details.name,
        categories_platforms=categories_platforms,
        platform_details=platform_details, category=category, task=task,
        type_task=type_task, taskuser=taskuser, campaign=campaign,
        list_place_holders=list_place_holders, form=form,
        AB_testing_result=AB_testing_result)
```

As I suspect the issue is from one of the parameters passed in "render_template", I decided to print the value of variable and the type.

This is the log:

```
2409 ==================================================================================

platform_details.name : Instagram <class 'str'>
categories_platforms : [[(1, 'Cold Messaging', 'cold_messaging', '<i class="mdi mdi-message-text-outline menu-icon"></i>', ''), [(15, 'Facebook', '<i class="mdi mdi-facebook-box"></i>', ''), (23, 'Google_Map', '<i class="mdi mdi-google-maps"></i>', ''), (22, 'Instagram', '<i class="mdi mdi-instagram"></i>', ''), (4, 'Linkedin', '<i class="mdi mdi-linkedin"></i>', ''), (45, 'Reddit', '<i class="mdi mdi-reddit"></i>', ''), (24, 'sms', '<i class="mdi mdi-comment-text"></i>', ''), (11, 'Telegram', '<i class="mdi mdi-telegram"></i>', ''), (3, 'Twitter', '<i class="mdi mdi-twitter"></i>', ''), (12, 'Whatsapp', '<i class="mdi mdi-whatsapp"></i>', '')]], [(2, 'Influencers', 'influencers', '<i class="mdi mdi-human-greeting menu-icon"></i>', ''), [(25, 'Facebook', '<i class="mdi mdi-facebook-box"></i>', ''), (26, 'Instagram', '<i class="mdi mdi-instagram"></i>', ''), (28, 'Linkedin', '<i class="mdi mdi-linkedin"></i>', ''), (9, 'Reddit', '<i class="mdi mdi-reddit"></i>', ''), (29, 'Telegram', '<i class="mdi mdi-telegram"></i>', ''), (42, 'TikTok', '', 'tiktok_blue.png'), (27, 'Twitter', '<i class="mdi mdi-twitter"></i>', ''), (10, 'Youtube', '<i class="mdi mdi-youtube"></i>', '')]], [(3, 'Scraping', 'scraping', '<i class="mdi mdi-database menu-icon"></i>', ''), [(7, 'Craigslist', '', 'craigslist_blue.png'), (36, 'Facebook', '<i class="mdi mdi-facebook-box"></i>', ''), (35, 'Google_Map', '<i class="mdi mdi-google-maps"></i>', ''), (33, 'Instagram', '<i class="mdi mdi-instagram"></i>', ''), (5, 'Leboncoin', '', 'leboncoin_blue.png'), (31, 'Linkedin', '<i class="mdi mdi-linkedin"></i>', ''), (8, 'Pages Jaunes', '', 'pagesjaunes_blue.png'), (6, 'YellowPages', '', 'yellow_pages_blue.png')]], [(4, 'Authority', 'authority', '<i class="mdi mdi-shape-plus menu-icon"></i>', ''), [(34, 'Facebook', '<i class="mdi mdi-facebook-box"></i>', ''), (37, 'Instagram', '<i class="mdi mdi-instagram"></i>', ''), (43, 'Linkedin', '<i class="mdi mdi-linkedin"></i>', ''), (44, 'TikTok', '', 'tiktok_blue.png'), (38, 'Twitter', '<i class="mdi mdi-twitter"></i>', '')]], [(5, 'Freelancer', 'freelancer', '<i class="mdi mdi-worker menu-icon"></i>', ''), [(39, 'Freelancer', '', 'freelancer_blue.png'), (40, 'Upwork', '', 'upwork_blue.png')]]] <class 'list'>
 platform_details : Platform('37','Instagram','instagram_automation.jpg','<h3 class="card-title" style="font-size:1.1em;">
          <i class="mdi mdi-download"></i>
          Your data
      </h3>

      <p>
          After the job is done, you will find the report of activity in the campaign report page.
      </p>
      <p>
          It can take a very long time to automate safetly.
      <p>
          The more tasks PhoneBot has to do, the more time it will take to accomplish this Authority task. If you are in hurry, please create a new campaign dedicated only to Authority.
      </p>','4',          '<i class="mdi mdi-instagram"></i>','','','','1') <class 'dashboard.models.Platform'>
 category : Category('4','Authority','authority','<i class="mdi mdi-shape-plus menu-icon"></i>','','','') <class 'dashboard.models.Category'>
 task : Task('34','Auto-Follow','<p>PhoneBot will follow the Instagram Followers of specific accounts (i.e.: some influencers or your competitors). You need to provide a list of urls of these specific accounts. ','<h3 class="card-title" style="font-size:1.1em;">
          <i class="mdi mdi-information-outline"></i>
          NOTIFICATION
      </h3>

      <p>You will be able to see the progress of this task on the report home page of your campaign .</p>
     </p>',          '37','7','75','1','1','1') <class 'dashboard.models.Task'>
type_task : TypeTask('7','Follow') <class 'dashboard.models.TypeTask'>
taskuser : TaskUser('1182','None','34','44','None','None',          'None',None',   'None',   'None',   'None',   'None',   'None',   'None',   'None',   'None',   'None',   'None',   'None',   'None',   'None',   'None',   'None',   'None',   'None',   'None',   'None',   'None',   'None',   'None',   'None',   'None',   'None',   'None',   'None',   'None',   'None',   'None',   'None',   'None',   'None',   'None',   'None',   'None',   'None',   'None',   'None',   'None',   'None',   'None',   'None',   'None') <class 'dashboard.models.TaskUser'>
campaign : Campaign('44','1','40','popop','2021-06-29 11:10:57','178') <class 'dashboard.models.Campaign'>
list_place_holders : {username}, {random_abc} <class 'str'>
form : <dashboard.forms.NewTaskUserForm object at 0x7f0d8ec25490> <class 'dashboard.forms.NewTaskUserForm'>
AB_testing_result : (1182, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) <class 'tuple'>

[2021-09-24 08:07:21,505] ERROR in app: Exception on /task_user/1182/edit [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/www/dashboard.phonebot.co/dashboard.phone_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2070, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/www/dashboard.phonebot.co/dashboard.phone_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "/home/www/dashboard.phonebot.co/dashboard.phone_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1537, in finalize_request
    response = self.process_response(response)
  File "/home/www/dashboard.phonebot.co/dashboard.phone_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1886, in process_response
    self.session_interface.save_session(self, ctx.session, response)
  File "/home/www/dashboard.phonebot.co/dashboard.phone_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/sessions.py", line 394, in save_session
    val = self.get_signing_serializer(app).dumps(dict(session))  # type: ignore
  File "/home/www/dashboard.phonebot.co/dashboard.phone_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/itsdangerous/serializer.py", line 207, in dumps
    payload = want_bytes(self.dump_payload(obj))
  File "/home/www/dashboard.phonebot.co/dashboard.phone_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/itsdangerous/url_safe.py", line 53, in dump_payload
    json = super().dump_payload(obj)
  File "/home/www/dashboard.phonebot.co/dashboard.phone_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/itsdangerous/serializer.py", line 169, in dump_payload
    return want_bytes(self.serializer.dumps(obj, **self.serializer_kwargs))
  File "/home/www/dashboard.phonebot.co/dashboard.phone_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/json/tag.py", line 308, in dumps
    return dumps(self.tag(value), separators=(",", ":"))
  File "/home/www/dashboard.phonebot.co/dashboard.phone_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/json/__init__.py", line 129, in dumps
    rv = _json.dumps(obj, **kwargs)
  File "/www/server/panel/pyenv/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/www/server/panel/pyenv/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/www/server/panel/pyenv/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/home/www/dashboard.phonebot.co/dashboard.phone_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/json/__init__.py", line 56, in default
    return super().default(o)
  File "/www/server/panel/pyenv/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type Row is not JSON serializable
[2021-09-24 08:07:21,507] ERROR in app: Request finalizing failed with an error while handling an error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/www/dashboard.phonebot.co/dashboard.phone_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2070, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/www/dashboard.phonebot.co/dashboard.phone_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "/home/www/dashboard.phonebot.co/dashboard.phone_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1537, in finalize_request
    response = self.process_response(response)
  File "/home/www/dashboard.phonebot.co/dashboard.phone_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1886, in process_response
    self.session_interface.save_session(self, ctx.session, response)
  File "/home/www/dashboard.phonebot.co/dashboard.phone_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/sessions.py", line 394, in save_session
    val = self.get_signing_serializer(app).dumps(dict(session))  # type: ignore
  File "/home/www/dashboard.phonebot.co/dashboard.phone_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/itsdangerous/serializer.py", line 207, in dumps
    payload = want_bytes(self.dump_payload(obj))
  File "/home/www/dashboard.phonebot.co/dashboard.phone_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/itsdangerous/url_safe.py", line 53, in dump_payload
    json = super().dump_payload(obj)
  File "/home/www/dashboard.phonebot.co/dashboard.phone_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/itsdangerous/serializer.py", line 169, in dump_payload
    return want_bytes(self.serializer.dumps(obj, **self.serializer_kwargs))
  File "/home/www/dashboard.phonebot.co/dashboard.phone_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/json/tag.py", line 308, in dumps
    return dumps(self.tag(value), separators=(",", ":"))
  File "/home/www/dashboard.phonebot.co/dashboard.phone_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/json/__init__.py", line 129, in dumps
    rv = _json.dumps(obj, **kwargs)
  File "/www/server/panel/pyenv/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/www/server/panel/pyenv/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/www/server/panel/pyenv/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/home/www/dashboard.phonebot.co/dashboard.phone_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/json/__init__.py", line 56, in default
    return super().default(o)
  File "/www/server/panel/pyenv/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type Row is not JSON serializable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/www/dashboard.phonebot.co/dashboard.phone_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1537, in finalize_request
    response = self.process_response(response)
  File "/home/www/dashboard.phonebot.co/dashboard.phone_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1886, in process_response
    self.session_interface.save_session(self, ctx.session, response)
  File "/home/www/dashboard.phonebot.co/dashboard.phone_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/sessions.py", line 394, in save_session
    val = self.get_signing_serializer(app).dumps(dict(session))  # type: ignore
  File "/home/www/dashboard.phonebot.co/dashboard.phone_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/itsdangerous/serializer.py", line 207, in dumps
    payload = want_bytes(self.dump_payload(obj))
  File "/home/www/dashboard.phonebot.co/dashboard.phone_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/itsdangerous/url_safe.py", line 53, in dump_payload
    json = super().dump_payload(obj)
  File "/home/www/dashboard.phonebot.co/dashboard.phone_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/itsdangerous/serializer.py", line 169, in dump_payload
    return want_bytes(self.serializer.dumps(obj, **self.serializer_kwargs))
  File "/home/www/dashboard.phonebot.co/dashboard.phone_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/json/tag.py", line 308, in dumps
    return dumps(self.tag(value), separators=(",", ":"))
  File "/home/www/dashboard.phonebot.co/dashboard.phone_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/json/__init__.py", line 129, in dumps
    rv = _json.dumps(obj, **kwargs)
  File "/www/server/panel/pyenv/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/www/server/panel/pyenv/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/www/server/panel/pyenv/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/home/www/dashboard.phonebot.co/dashboard.phone_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/json/__init__.py", line 56, in default
    return super().default(o)
  File "/www/server/panel/pyenv/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type Row is not JSON serializable
```

To be sure the issue is not from the template "task.html", I empty it and reproduced the error. I get the same error logs.

I don't understand why there is this json issue when I don't use json.
Is it "render_template" which jsonify the data before to pass to template?
DOes anyone already faced this issue?

Here someone tried to fix it but without success ((
https://youtu.be/4su2FDJRrH8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to serialise is coming from finalize_request->save_session. So this is post-processing by the framework. Some frameworks save session content to disk, to free memory. (There could be a setting to control this). You have probably stored the Row object in session, so its trying to serialise that, and hence the error. Solution is to not save Row in the session, or make Row serializable. See https://pynative.com/make-python-class-json-serializable/

Comment: Thank you so much. This is interesting. I will work on it and may come back to you.

Comment: I don't understand because I am saving in session none of the parameters of render_template. neither I use JSON. So I don't know how to handle your tutorial in my particular case.

Comment: Hi, The error is clear that its not able to serialize the data. Means not able to create json.

Comment: @GauthierButtez, the save-session is not part of your business logic, but something that the framework does on its own to save session state.Have you stored Row object in session or not ? There could be a flag to modify this behaviour. Or, use the tutorial to make the Row class serializable.

Comment: thanks @manojmo. I am using the object flask "session" to save some data during user's session. But none of the session dictionary values are passed to "render_template". This is trigging me.??

Comment: Thank you so much. I get it! It was an issue with the session object. I was storing a tuple in the dictionary "session". I changed and it works now!